# Login to different site

Tags: php, authentication

I would like to enable an "auto login" button for my users. By pressing the button the users will be logged in to a different site with the username and password that I have added inside the code.
My site uses php and this site is written on asp.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whats the reason for this behavior? You can just add auth flag into session (or what do you use as storage) as username/password are hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to use [CURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) in PHP in order to send the POST data to your ASP script in the remote site.

Nevertheless, the ASP site might have some inner-validations which can lead to refuse your request, it's worth a try, though!

To set CURL to user POST, check out the [setopt CURL function options](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), you have to set the CURLOPT_POST option to TRUE, but you might find that (depending on the ASP site), you need to activate/deactivate other options.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the website you're trying to login to.

In a website not using a key-based system for each visitor this can be achieved pretty easily.

- First navigate to the page yourself that contains the login form and show it's page source.
- Jot down every `<input>`-tag's name and value and determine which one is the username & password. Also note the form's action to see where the data is going towards.
- Now you can use `curl` to send a user to the website, just inject the post data and apply your own username & password to it.

Answer (score 0):

A. **If you don't own the remote site:**
Have you tried to post your authentication parameters directly to the ASP.net page? Then you could also try using CURL but either way, be rest assured that the site owner might lock you out anytime by implementing simple [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) protection.

B. **If you own the remote site:**
You can share sessions with a unique key using a common database.